# SSRS site setting permission

Tags: reporting-services, permissions, sql-server-2016

I'm new to SSRS 2016 and I'm just on the configuration part. I'm facing a problem when trying to add new role or add new user to an existing role, I'm getting a permission error. the user I'm using is a network user and I also define the same user name as local user on the server. both belongs to local administrators group. The Error message I get:"An error has occurred. 
You do not have permission for this operation. Contact your administrator to obtain the necessary permissions"
can anyone tell me what permission do I need in order to end this nightmare?
[screenshot to the error I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOcka.png)

Comment: I would suggest adding the actual error text to your question so that it appears in searches.

Comment: In prior versions, I've had to run a browser as admin to give the Content Manager permission to myself. Though, things have changed...

Comment: The thing is that i can't grant any role using the reporting services configuration manager. Everything I try to update end with the same error message

Answer (score 4):

Figure it out, IE doesnt allow changing rules. using chrome did the trick

Comment: does anyone know WHY?  what kind of crazy issue is it that would block a local administrator from performing administrative tasks?  This is weird.  I have 2 instances - one running in an "all-in-one" box and i have no issues.  The second is a 2-server environment web/db setup.  They're configured identically (incidentally, for testing purposes, using the same service accounts across the board).....  the all-in-one instance has no issues with ANY browser, but the 2-server farm does....  chrome works on both.

Comment: Chiming in 4 years later. I had the opposite issue, on Chrome it didn't work but on IE it did. Hoping this helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The error you're seeing is because SSRS 2016 has some XAML Browser Application elements that are part of the [Windows Presentation Foundation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/app-development/wpf-xaml-browser-applications-overview) graphical subsystem.

The reason Chrome works is because you (most likely) have the .NET Framework 3.5 installed; but it could be that Chrome has native support XAML applications. I'm postulating this based on the fact the [Firefox requires the .NET Framework 3.5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/app-development/firefox-add-ons-to-support-net-application-deployment) to be installed, in order to run XBAP and loose XAML files.

Internet Explorer supports XBAP / loose XAML natively, but it isn't enabled by default, as the default security level for Internet sites is set to Medium-High. Adding an SSRS 2016 site to the list of Trusted Sites or changing the Internet Zone security level to Medium, will enable XAML application support.

[image: Internet Options/Security]